# How to resize the new layouts' components in an android studio project?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have developed an application with four main layouts. before creating the third and foreth layout I had used batch import to create mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi version of image buttons, then I had created the layout-large and layout-xlarge to automatically put the appropriate images into the layouts. it fortunately worked. I had the proper image and layout sizes for tablet 7 and 10. Now, I have followed the same structure for the new layouts and it surprisingly doesn't put the proper new images in the new layouts. It can't match the master detail/flow activity according the size of phone/tablet (this activity is a template activity in android studio) too. What is the problem in your opinion and what should I do to fix it? I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Make **drawable-sw600dp** and  **drawable-sw720dp** directory under **res** directory and keep all the images for tablet 7 and 10.

Comment: I kept all the hdpi and xhdpi images in these directories. But the sizes are still medium.

Comment: make sure you have created layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp directory under res directory and keep all layout files under these for tablet 7 and 10.

Comment: layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720dp directories are under res and related layout files are kept under these directories. The problem is still the same.

Comment: please post layout?